# google treemap by Yahoo API

Tags: treemap

i need add Yahoo Fiance data of sectors to google treemap

```
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap
```

by Yahoo API. 
How add code to google treemap??

Answer (score 0):

Solution found! All turned out to be not so difficult.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/epoxa/85bk44mh/1/`
```